# Unable to restart windows server 2012 R2 VM . also task manager is not responding

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008-r2, task-manager, visual-studio-2012

I was working on visual studio professional 2012 inside my windows server 2012 R2. then I stop running the visual studio ,, where it hangs and stop responding. then I tried to open Task Manager to force stopping the VS , but also the task manager is not responding. now I tried restarting the VM ,, but it did not restart. here is how my VM looks like:-

[image]

so can anyone advice on this please ? how I can restart or stop VS from running ?

Answer (score 0):

If the GUI/task manager is not responding, it might be worthwhile to try and kill the process using the command prompt. A good walkthrough is provided here: http://tweaks.com/windows/39559/kill-processes-from-command-prompt/ .

Additionally, sysinternals PSKill could be a useful option to try remotely if needed. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/pskill.aspx